# Javascript: add integer after second character of string

Tags: javascript

My CMS is exporting strings into a span element like this:

```
<span class="starting-hour 0900">0900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1900</span>
```

I need the 0900 and 1900 as a class so I can add some CSS to them to fill up a bar. This is working fine, but it also exports it as the starting and ending hour so you see '0900' and '1900' in the frontend. I would like to split these strings up so I can add a ':' after the second integer with Javascript. So in this way the strings would be shown as: '09:00' and '19:00' in the frontend.

My knowledge of Javascript is very basic so I don't know how to get this started. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're not telling us anything about your CMS I get you are looking for a solution in JS? Because IMO this logic should go in the CMS as well (The `:` addition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select all elements with on of the classes, then add it like below

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.starting-hour, .ending-hour').forEach(e => {
  e.innerText = e.innerText.padStart(4, 0);
  e.innerText = e.innerText.substring(0, 2) + ':' + e.innerText.substring(2)
})
```

```html
<span class="starting-hour 0900">0900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1900</span>
<span class="starting-hour 0900">900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1900</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a reusable function that will return you the hour representation of the values in `span`:

```js
function getHours(val){
  return val.substr(0,2)+':'+val.substr(2,4);
}

var start = document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerText;
document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerText = getHours(start);

var end = document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerText;
document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerText = getHours(end);
```

```html
<span class="starting-hour 0900">0900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1900</span>
```

But, if you do not have exactly four character long `hhhh` in your span then use this:

```js
function getHours(val){
  return val.substr(0,val.length-2)+':'+val.substr(val.length-2,val.length);
}

var start = document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerText;
document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerText = getHours(start);

var end = document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerText;
document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerText = getHours(end);
```

```html
<span class="starting-hour 0900">900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1000</span>
```

Comment: this makes the assumption that the hour will **always** be in the format of `hhhh` and not in the format of **hhh**, so it'll not work for a `900` string.

Comment: @Adelin OP has mentioned that so I assume he have that. Otherwise OP should have mentioned that in his example.

Comment: I'd probably use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` but better imho to wrap it in a function as you've done

Comment: Because OPs requirements is one thing, people-with-similar-question-reaching-this-answer's requirements will be another thing so, for clarity, we must mention the assumption a solution will make

Comment: @DarrenSweeney agree with `innerText`

Comment: @Adelin sure mate. Added a new snippet with that dynamic behaviour

Comment: Agreed @Adelin, would make it better for future visitors - a variable string length might be a different question though.

Comment: You could simply use String.padStart @AnkitAgarwal

Answer (score 0):

Taking from Ankit's answer, I made code little `dynamic` to satisfy both `4 digits` and `3 digits` time example and added both codes.

```js
function getHours(val){
  return val.substr(0,val.length - 2)+':'+val.substr(val.length - 2,val.length);
}

var start = document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerHTML = getHours(start);

var end = document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerHTML = getHours(end);


var start = document.querySelector('.starting-hour-two').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.starting-hour-two').innerHTML = getHours(start);

var end = document.querySelector('.ending-hour-two').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.ending-hour-two').innerHTML = getHours(end);
```

```html
<span class="starting-hour 0900">0900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1900</span>

<br>
<br>

<span class="starting-hour-two 900">900</span> - <span class="ending-hour-two 100">100</span>
```

```js
function getHours(val){
  return val.substr(0,val.length - 2)+':'+val.substr(val.length - 2,val.length);
}

var start = document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.starting-hour').innerHTML = getHours(start);

var end = document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.ending-hour').innerHTML = getHours(end);

var start = document.querySelector('.starting-hour-two').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.starting-hour-two').innerHTML = getHours(start);

var end = document.querySelector('.ending-hour-two').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('.ending-hour-two').innerHTML = getHours(end);
```

```html
<span class="starting-hour 0900">0900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1900</span>

<span class="starting-hour-two 900">900</span> - <span class="ending-hour-two 100">100</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since yout time is always 4 characters long, it makes it easy to slice the string, put in a : then put them together.

```
var str1 = "0900".slice(0,2);
var str2 = "0900".slice(2,4);
var time = str1 + ":" + str2;
alert(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addColon` function takes an `element` and sets its `innerText` to itself, but with the a colon inserted before the last two digits.

Use any method you want to select your `span` elements and pass them over to `addColon`. I've gone with a `querySelector` and a `forEach` iterator.

```js
const addColon = el => el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(/(\d){2}$/, ":$&");

const timeStamps = document.querySelectorAll("span[class*='-hour']");

timeStamps.forEach(stamp => addColon(stamp));
```

```html
<span class="starting-hour 0900">0900</span> - <span class="ending-hour 1900">1900</span>
```